# How can I convert Dataframe to H2O in Scala?

Tags: scala, rdd, h2o

thanks for asking my question. I'm now working on convert RDD to DF to H2O. I'm quite stuck with the H2O part. How can I convert Scala DataFrame to H2O?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to import the H2OFrame first

```
import water.fvec.H2OFrame
```

this is an implicit conversion from DataFrame ("oldFrame") to H2OFrame 
("newFrame")

```
val newFrame:H2OFrame = oldFrame
```